# RoR ActiveRecord::Base uniq undefined when trying to uniq.pluck(:column_name)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, uniq

so I have a very simple model called Movies.  I'm trying to add a class method which returns a tidy list of the ratings assigned to movies in the database.  It seems I'd want to call `Movie.uniq.pluck(:rating)`

So I've added the method like so:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.all_ratings
        self.uniq.pluck(:rating)
    end

end
```

but it just doesn't work.  When it runs I get: `undefined method`uniq' for #`...  I've tried including ActiveRecord::Calculations but that doesn't seem to help either.  I also put a breakpoint in after 'def...' to inspect what methods self had and sure enough, uniq wasn't among them...

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I just don't quite get what it is.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
ó_ò
```

Comment: What version of rails are you using? (uniq was added in 3.2.1 if my memory is correct)

Comment: So that would answer that then.  Thank you :)

Comment: `uniq` is a Ruby method. I think its `pluck` that is pretty recent.

Answer (score 2):

`uniq` is a Ruby method, and available even for 1.8.7. The problem is `uniq` is an `Array` method.

So you probably need to call `uniq` on something like `Movie.all`.

Comment: Yes, but in the more recent Rails documentation, ActiveRecord::Calculations.uniq.pluck(:column_name) is well defined.  I hadn't accounted for the fact that it was more recent than the version I was using, hence the 2 day headache.  Of course, there are more verbose ways to do the same thing, as you suggest.

Comment: I was actually able to use uniq on a class for Rails 5.0.1 but it no longer worked in 5.1.2 and had to add the .all method to my class.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

uniq is an array method. When you put `self.uniq` inside `self.all_ratings`, self refers to the Movie class, it wont point to any collection

So first get the collection as you want

```
result = Movie.all

(or)

result = Movie.where({})
```

and then use the uniq method for the result